# InputAccessoryView Border?

Tags: ios, keyboard, border, accessory

I'm creating a custom keyboard accessory view. I am currently about 95% done with it. The only thing I have left is to remove the 1px (or 2px?) line above the native iOS keyboard. Is there a way to add a border to the inputaccessoryview so I can use the same color as the keyboard gradient to eliminate the black bar?

[Picture Example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1fx0duuvtxa5093/keyboardaccess.png)

If the boarder isn't possible what is the next most logical thing to do with my source code?

**signInViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface signInViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate> {
AVAudioPlayer *sound;
UIButton *myButton;
UITextField *textFieldOne;
UIButton *gmailButton;
UIButton *meButton;
UIButton *yahooButton;
UIButton *outlookButton;
UIView *inputAccView;
UIButton *aolButton;
UIButton *milButton;
}


- (IBAction)playSwoosh:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)toggleUIButtonImage:(id)sender;

- (IBAction)backgroundTouched:(id)sender;



@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textFieldOne;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textFieldTwo;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *gmailButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *meButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *yahooButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *outlookButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *aolButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *milButton;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UIButton *myButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIView *inputAccView;

@end
```

and **signInViewController.m**

```
#import "signInViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface signInViewController ()

@end

@implementation signInViewController

@synthesize myButton = _myButton;
@synthesize textFieldOne = _textFieldOne;
@synthesize textFieldTwo = _textFieldTwo;
@synthesize inputAccView;
@synthesize gmailButton;
@synthesize yahooButton;
@synthesize meButton;
@synthesize outlookButton;
@synthesize aolButton;
@synthesize milButton;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
}
return self;
}

- (void)gmailButtonTapped
{
self.textFieldOne.text = [self.textFieldOne.text stringByAppendingString:@"@gmail.com"];
}

- (void)meButtonTapped
{
self.textFieldOne.text = [self.textFieldOne.text stringByAppendingString:@"@me.com"];
}

- (void)outlookButtonTapped
{
self.textFieldOne.text = [self.textFieldOne.text stringByAppendingString:@"@outlook.com"];
}

- (void)yahooButtonTapped
{
self.textFieldOne.text = [self.textFieldOne.text stringByAppendingString:@"@yahoo.com"];
}

- (void)aolButtonTapped
{
self.textFieldOne.text = [self.textFieldOne.text stringByAppendingString:@"@aol.com"];
}

- (void)milButtonTapped
{
self.textFieldOne.text = [self.textFieldOne.text stringByAppendingString:@"@mail.mil"];
}


- (void)createInputAccessoryView {
inputAccView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 310.0, 40.0)];
[inputAccView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.569 green:0.600 blue:0.643 alpha:1.000]];
[inputAccView setAlpha: 0.8];     

// GMAIL BUTTON ADDED

gmailButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
[gmailButton setFrame:CGRectMake(9.5, 4.5, 60.0, 30.0)];
[gmailButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(241/255.0) green:(242/255.0) blue:(242/255.0) alpha:1]];
[inputAccView addSubview:gmailButton];

gmailButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
gmailButton.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
gmailButton.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
gmailButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
gmailButton.layer.shadowRadius = 2;
gmailButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f);

[gmailButton setTitle:@"@Gmail" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[gmailButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[gmailButton setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
gmailButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue Bold" size:12];

[gmailButton addTarget:self action:@selector(gmailButtonTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// ME BUTTON ADDED

meButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
[meButton setFrame:CGRectMake(73.5, 4.5, 40.0, 30.0)];
[meButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(241/255.0) green:(242/255.0) blue:(242/255.0) alpha:1]];
[inputAccView addSubview:meButton];

meButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
meButton.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
meButton.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
meButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
meButton.layer.shadowRadius = 2;
meButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f);

[meButton setTitle:@"@Me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[meButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[meButton setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
meButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue Bold" size:12];

[meButton addTarget:self action:@selector(meButtonTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// YAHOO BUTTON ADDED

yahooButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
[yahooButton setFrame:CGRectMake(117.5, 4.5, 65.0, 30.0)];
[yahooButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(241/255.0) green:(242/255.0) blue:(242/255.0) alpha:1]];
[inputAccView addSubview:yahooButton];

yahooButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
yahooButton.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
yahooButton.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
yahooButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
yahooButton.layer.shadowRadius = 2;
yahooButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f);

[yahooButton setTitle:@"@Yahoo" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[yahooButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[yahooButton setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
yahooButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue Bold" size:12];

[yahooButton addTarget:self action:@selector(yahooButtonTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// OUTLOOK BUTTON ADDED

outlookButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
[outlookButton setFrame:CGRectMake(186.5, 4.5, 77.0, 30.0)];
[outlookButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(241/255.0) green:(242/255.0) blue:(242/255.0) alpha:1]];
[inputAccView addSubview:outlookButton];

outlookButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
outlookButton.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
outlookButton.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
outlookButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
outlookButton.layer.shadowRadius = 2;
outlookButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f);

[outlookButton setTitle:@"@Outlook" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[outlookButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[outlookButton setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
outlookButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue Bold" size:12];

[outlookButton addTarget:self action:@selector(outlookButtonTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// AOL BUTTON ADDED

aolButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
[aolButton setFrame:CGRectMake(267.5, 4.5, 41.0, 30.0)];
[aolButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(241/255.0) green:(242/255.0) blue:(242/255.0) alpha:1]];
[inputAccView addSubview:aolButton];

aolButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
aolButton.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
aolButton.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
aolButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
aolButton.layer.shadowRadius = 2;
aolButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f);

[aolButton setTitle:@"@Aol" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[aolButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[aolButton setTitleColor:[UIColor grayColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
aolButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue Bold" size:12];

[aolButton addTarget:self action:@selector(aolButtonTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}

- (IBAction)backgroundTouched:(id)sender {
[_textFieldOne resignFirstResponder];
[_textFieldTwo resignFirstResponder];
}


- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

if (textField == self.textFieldOne) {
    [self createInputAccessoryView];
    [textField setInputAccessoryView:inputAccView];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, (self.view.frame.origin.y - 95), self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
} else if (textField == self.textFieldTwo) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, (self.view.frame.origin.y - 95), self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
if (textField == self.textFieldOne) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, (self.view.frame.origin.y + 95), self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
} else if (textField == self.textFieldTwo) {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, (self.view.frame.origin.y + 95), self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
}


- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
NSInteger nextTag = textField.tag + 1;
UIResponder* nextResponder = [textField.superview viewWithTag:nextTag];
if (nextResponder) {
    [nextResponder becomeFirstResponder];
} else {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
return  NO;
}
```

Comment: also. I know there is a inputAccView.layer.border = 1; 

However, that doesn't do the outside of the accview, it only borders the inside. I've tried that already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after playing around with it, I've decided not to add a boarder because all it did was include an inside boarder. I simply just drew an object to cover it up. But I did find a great resource for those still wondering how to do it! This is another method that would be great for implementation. For you new developers that just want a quick fix, someone did offer for me to simply create another button that was the length of the screen and 3 px high to cover it up, but we all know that s the wrong answer. Just a tip for any newbies

[Extend iOS Keyboard Gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107796/how-to-extend-keyboard-gradient-on-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

The `KeyboardAccessoryView` has a special property `hideBorder` according to the docs at https://github.com/ardaogulcan/react-native-keyboard-accessory
I suppose `InputAccessoryView` has the same property.