# Matching keyboard accessory view background color with keyboard color

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikeyboard

I am trying to put a accessory view on top of default UIKeyboard. I want to match the background color of the accessory view to that of keyboard both for iOS 6 and iOS 7. I am trying with below RGB which is not helping.

If anyone has done this before, please suggest.

```
For iOS 6
myAccessoryView.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:105.0f/255.0f green:114.0f/255.0f blue:125.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

For iOS 7
myAccessoryView.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(81.0f / 255.0f) green:(81.0f / 255.0f) blue:(81.0f / 255.0f) alpha:0.98f]
```

Answer (score 5):

For iOS7 you could use UIInputView. to support iOS6 you will have to invest some more work, basically subclassing a UIToolBar and setting the correct tintColor. See [How to extend keyboard gradient on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107796/how-to-extend-keyboard-gradient-on-iphone) for more information

Comment: Do you know how to add a `UIToolbar` inside `UIInputView`? The toolbar doesn't appear if I just do `uiInputView.addSubview(uiToolbar)`

Comment: If I also set a frame (or use auto layout constraints), it works for me. If you still experience troubles, it's best to ask a new question :)