# iOS 11: Accessory view that matches the new blur of the keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

This may have been the case previous to iOS 11, but I'm noticing it now. The default iOS 11 keyboard seems to use a new blur effect that I can not match using any of the `UIBlurEffect` styles. I have an accessory view that appears above the keyboard whose background I want to match the keyboard below. I essentially want the accessory view to look like a seamless extension of the keyboard. Has anyone figured out a way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matching keyboard accessory view background color with keyboard color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23769014/matching-keyboard-accessory-view-background-color-with-keyboard-color)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using `UIInputView` as an accessory view. Don't forget to init it with `UIInputView.Style.keyboard`

e.g.:

`let keyboardInputView = UIInputView(frame: .zero, inputViewStyle: .keyboard)`